# Smartgwt Enable Scrolling in disabled grid

Tags: java, gwt, scroll, grid, smartgwt

I have a small smartgwt listgrid which can only display 3 records at a time, but can theoretically have more then 10 records. Our UI design is to enable the grid only when the user enters editing mode. As long as this does not happen, the user should not be able to select(assign) a record. The grid contains only a selection checkbox column and a name column. Here's the code for the selection.

```
gridRealmDt.setCanSelectAll(false);
gridRealmDt.setSelectionType(SelectionStyle.SIMPLE);
gridRealmDt.setSelectionAppearance(SelectionAppearance.CHECKBOX);
```

But as long is the grid is disabled scrolling is also disabled. Is there a way to enable scrolling on a disabled grid? It would also be OK, to not disable the grid and only prevent selection of the checkboxes. Is there a way to set the grid to read only mode or something?

We use smartgwt 6.0p and gwt 2.6.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar case. We went on to use:

```
set_canEdit(boolean canEdit)
```

on all of the records.

Answer (score 0):

Setting canEdit unfortunately did not change the behavoir on our side. I solved it with an SelectionUpdated handler where I restore the DB state in the grid whenenver selection changes on the GUI side. I also had to create a field in my class to prevent endless loops when changing selections via code.